# Has PHP's attitude towards exceptions changed in version 5.4.10?

Tags: php

The following would work in PHP 5.3, but not in PHP 5.4.10.

```
throw new Custom_Exception();

class Custom_Exception extends Exception {}
```

PHP 5.4.10 would respond with the following fatal error:

> Class 'Custom_Exception' not found in ...

Does anyone know why?

p.s. Moving the class definition above the throw statement fixes it.

Comment: @nathanhayfield, Nope, it only happens with `throw`.

Comment: Might be a bug, works both in `5.4.9` and `5.5-dev`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XTloFa

Comment: @Niko, According to the following service, it works in 5.4.10 either, but it doesn't - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/. Have you tested it on a real machine?

Comment: Could you then describe your local setup? Are you running a file that contains only the above lines or do you experience this error in an actual application? Most likely, the error lies somewhere else...

Comment: +1 works in 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5

Comment: @Niko, Yes, I've been testing it using a single file and my set up is a clean installation of the latest MAMP.

Comment: @LukeMills, Thanks for taking the time to test it.

Comment: Works on 5.4.9, Linux.

Comment: Can you try something like the following?

`<?php
new Foo();
class Foo {}`

Comment: `phpinfo()` may be helpful. Perhaps it's a misbehaving extension or a configuration issue.

Comment: did you consider namespaces, which have been introduced in php5.4? try  `throw new \Custom_Exception();`

Comment: Your code works fine in 5.0 onwards; [proof](http://3v4l.org/XaECZ)

Comment: It's quite possible that it's caused by APC, but without knowing your setup this problem is simply too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into a file called test.php, and downloaded [php-5.4.10](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.4.10-Win32-VC9-x86.zip)

When I execute:

```
php -c php.ini-development -f test.php
```

I see the following output:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Custom_Exception' in test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in test.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Custom_Exception' in test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in test.php on line 3
```

I believe you have a configuration issue. Are you testing from the command-line?

Edit:

I also compared do_bind_inherited_class in zend_compile.c for both versions.

[zend_compile.c from 5.3](https://raw.github.com/php/php-src/PHP-5.3/Zend/zend_compile.c)

[zend_compile.c from 5.4.10](https://raw.github.com/php/php-src/PHP-5.4.10/Zend/zend_compile.c)

It looks like they only added support for traits.

My answer is: No, I do not believe the attitude has changed.

Comment: This is a comment; besides, it could be condensed to simply http://3v4l.org/XaECZ

Comment: @Jack: Before I posted my answer I was searching for that site, thank you! I think mine is an answer, I appear to be the first one who tested the same version, and also the only one who answered the question posed by the OP. (No, the attitude has not changed)

Comment: To be fair, the "answer" to the question was already given in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078219/has-phps-attitude-towards-exceptions-changed-in-version-5-4-10/16827225?noredirect=1#comment21206563_15078219). Also, it doesn't answer *why* this happens for OP only (so it seems).